# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "odoo13"

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-13

I am new to odoo cms. And Iam trying to import a dump SQL file from another odoo. While restoring the dump SQL the following error happened.

> psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "odoo13"

Could any one please help me to solve this issue

Comment: the error message is super clear

Comment: @eshirvana I am new to both postgresql,odoo .Could you please guid me

Comment: the authentication is failing , meaning the user/password is not correct or user  "odoo13" doesn't have enough privilege to access database

Answer (score 0):

locate the file :
pg_hba.conf
by using locate command if it's not installed you can installed by :
sudo apt install mlocate
then use it such as :
locate pg_hba.conf
when you will find the bath copy the path to modify it's content such as :
sudo nano THEPATH
inside the path change every local peer to trust or md5